# Find where systemd unit dependency comes from

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd, nordvpn

### Actual question

I have a target (`network-online.target`) which is waiting for a service.  The service is an instance of a template which has `Before=network-online.target` but I think I removed that from the specific instance with a drop-in.  However, the target still waits for that service to (fail to) start.

I can see from `systemd-analyze dot` that the `network-online.target` still happens After the unit, but I canʼt see *why* so I canʼt fix it.  Is there a way to see what line of what unit or configuration is causing that dependency, and hopefully clear it?

### More details I expect are irrelevant

I want to wait for a particular network interface to be online so I can start something *on* that interface.  The interface is defined by my VPN and doesnʼt usually *exist* until the VPN starts; the VPN wants `network-online.target` (because it needs to establish connections to things online) but this is usually fine because that doesnʼt wait for non-existent interfaces.  The VPN does not properly tell `systemd` when itʼs done setting up, but `systemd` can check for a specific interface with `systemd-networkd-wait-online@nordlynx.service`.  Unfortunately, *if* I run that, then it wants to happen before `network-online.target`, and therefore thereʼs no way for the VPN to start until after itʼs timed out.

Comment: It looks like if I *copy* the `networkd-wait-online@.service` file, name it something else, specialize it for nordlynx, and get rid of the parts connecting it to `network-online.target`, then it doesnʼt hold up the network, which is what I’d expect.  And sure enough, I’m starting my unit within a second *after* `nordlynx: Gained carrier`.  But apparently that is not enough to bind to the address there, so I’m waiting for the wrong thing still.